# Allow Landscape and Portrait but force app to remain in Portrait - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, device-orientation, mobfox

I have an app that is designed to run in portrait and all is well. However I have implemented Mobfox's vAds which require landscape mode.

At present I get the following error when the vAD is called

```
2013-01-08 23:44:05.109 Tv - IOS[1422:907] mobfox video did load
2013-01-08 23:44:05.125 Tv - IOS[1422:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
```

So the im thinking the fix would be allow for landscape in the app.

I need to force the app to run in portrait but allow for landscape when the vAd is called

So just to recap:

I need Portrait only orientation during normal app view and landscape/portrait during the mobFox vAd view is visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return `NO` for `shouldAutorotate`:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return NO;
}
```

Or if it is `YES` you need to return the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` (at least one), here its only allowing portrait:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually the code allows no rotation when returning 'NO'. Try that.
 
Otherwise return 'YES' and 'UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown'

Comment: The code provided is overrided by mobfox's vAd and i get the following error code 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Comment: The error message says that you are returning YES from shouldAutorotate. So, you have not changed the code as above. Not these methods should be in your root controller!

Comment: the methods are in the rootView controller and i have deffo put what you suggest. It is a strange one. This is why im thinking the the Mobfox vAd is overwriting the ShouldAutorotate method in the rootview controller

Comment: Then try setting it to 'YES' and returning 'UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown'

Comment: Same Problem Hannes, But thanks for trying to help :) It looks like this guy had the same problem https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/_kQhG05vISk/BSrTlkRAUOoJ

Comment: @user1922242 Please accept the answer if you have a conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after sleeping on this i managed to finally resolve the problem.

Solution: I had to subclass UINavigationController and override the autorotation methods and allow all rotations in in project > Target > summary settings

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
// pre-iOS 6 support 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: You strip me of my answer and then adds an identical answer and gives it your vote! Please explain.

Comment: I didn't realise I did this I am so sorry, I have restored it to its original. Please accept my apologies.